# Using custom Animation makes Modal large

Tags: html, css

So basically I am trying to replicate the "Jelly" Animation from this [website](http://bouncejs.com/). And in my HTML, I have the basic example of bootstrap modal from bootstrap. This:

```css
.animation-target {
  animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  3.4% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.316, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.407, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  4.7% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  6.81% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.659, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.893, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  9.41% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.883, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  10.21% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.942, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.226, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  13.61% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.332, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  14.11% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.331, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  17.52% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.208, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.239, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  18.72% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  21.32% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.196, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.069, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  24.32% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  25.23% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.134, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.938, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  29.03% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.897, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  29.93% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.899, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  35.54% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.979, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.962, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  36.74% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.972, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.979, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  41.04% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.961, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.022, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  44.44% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.966, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  52.15% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  59.86% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  63.26% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.992, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  75.28% {
    transform: matrix3d(2.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  85.49% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  90.69% {
    transform: matrix3d(1.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: matrix3d(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The modal and text seems to be very large when I add the animation and I do not understand why that happens. Here is the reproduce on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamujonelo/vp74js36/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jelly animation from bouncejs will double the size of the element hence you see the modal and text appear to be very large.

One way is to modify the matrix3d to reduce the size by half.
https://jsfiddle.net/0nyL9dc7/

```
@keyframes animation { 
  0% { transform: matrix3d(.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, .5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.4% { transform: matrix3d(0.658, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.703, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { transform: matrix3d(0.72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  6.81% { transform: matrix3d(0.83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.946, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { transform: matrix3d(0.941, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.21% { transform: matrix3d(0.971, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  13.61% { transform: matrix3d(1.061, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.166, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { transform: matrix3d(1.070, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  17.52% { transform: matrix3d(1.104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.093, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.32% { transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { transform: matrix3d(1.075, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.23% { transform: matrix3d(1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.969, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.03% { transform: matrix3d(1.031, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.948, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { transform: matrix3d(1.024, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { transform: matrix3d(0.990, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.981, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.74% { transform: matrix3d(0.986, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { transform: matrix3d(0.980, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.011, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.44% { transform: matrix3d(0.983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { transform: matrix3d(0.995, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  59.86% { transform: matrix3d(1.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { transform: matrix3d(1.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.996, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  75.28% { transform: matrix3d(1.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { transform: matrix3d(0.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  90.69% { transform: matrix3d(0.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

Another way is to add `scale(.5)` to `transform` in the animation keyframes to reduce the size by half.
https://jsfiddle.net/0cdahvx1/1/

```
@keyframes animation { 
  0% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.4% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.316, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.407, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  6.81% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.659, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.893, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.883, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.21% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.942, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.226, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  13.61% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.332, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.331, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  17.52% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.208, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.239, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.32% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.196, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.069, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.23% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.134, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.938, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.03% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.897, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.899, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.979, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.962, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.74% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.972, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.979, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.961, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.022, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.44% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.966, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  59.86% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.992, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  75.28% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  90.69% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(1.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { transform: scale(.5) matrix3d(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

Comment: Hi. What would be the better option? Scale or reduce the size of matrix3d?

Comment: I am not sure. I think the first method (reduce the size of matrix3d) is more performant as there is less computation. The advantage of second method (adding scale to transform) is that it easier to make changes, imagine if you want to update the scale size to .25 you can change it easily.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Will changing the scale by half effect modal responsiveness in anyway? I mean when changing the screen size and all

Comment: No. transform scale is relative to the size of the element and is not affected by screen size.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this!